# What does overflow mean in this case?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I came across this during my android training :

Specify the Actions in XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
```

This declares that the Search action should appear as an action button when room is available in the action bar, but the Settings action should always appear in the overflow. (By default, all actions appear in the overflow, but it's good practice to explicitly declare your design intentions for each action.)

what does overflow mean in this context? It seems to me some design construct. Please explain.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: WHERE IS OVERFLOW HEREIN THIS CODE...??

Comment: EXPLAIN HIS QUESTION WHAT YOU EXACTLY YOU WANT TO DO

Comment: @amitsharma not in the code, but in the explaination of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow is a menu item which groups menu items that are not immediately visible on the `ActionBar` in a separate menu which needs to be tapped to show the contents. Refer to the [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) documentation for more information.

[image: ActionBar elements]

In the image above, #3 represents the overflow menu. The documentation on [Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) also has quite a lot of information about this.

Comment: Thank you! you explained well.